# RegisterValidateFunction() For Flag pointer

Tags: crash, swift4, xcode10

While launching the app it gets crashed, Due to Ignoring RegisterValidateFunction() for flag pointer 0x10360c5d0: no flag found at that address. Please share how to solve this issue.